# Spring Background / Fire and Forget processing

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am developing an application using Spring 4.1.6 and Mongodb. I would like to perform some of the task in fire and forget mode e.g. once a method is accessed an entry in a collection will be made. I don't want to wait till writing to collection finishes or if it fails I don't need any notification either. How to achieve this using Spring.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this without spring but with spring i suggest to use [@Async](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async).

First you need to enable it. To do so on a Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Then in a bean use @Async on the method you want to be execute asynchronously

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Async
    void doSomething() {
        // this will be executed asynchronously
    }
}
```

Your method can have parameters too:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Async
    void doSomething(String s, int i, long l, Object o) {
        // this will be executed asynchronously
    }
}
```

In your case you don't need it but the method can return a Future:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Async
    Future<String> doSomething(String s, int i, long l, Object o) {
        // this will be executed asynchronously
        return new AsyncResult<>("result");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with Async but execution is not fire and forget. It waits till Async method finishes execution. I want fire and forget type of execution.

Comment: @Debopam, it should work with `@Async`, are you using it correctly? Can we see some code in the question?

Comment: Sorry I missed @EnableAsync in the configuration. It's working.